# N-tier application in asp.net webforms vs asp.net mvc regarding separations of concerns only

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multi-tier

***Regarding separations of concerns only,*** are there advantages of using ASP.NET MVC instead of ASP.NET webforms for a multi tier  application with an user Interface layer, a Business Logic layer and a Data Access layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I say stick to what you are comfortable with.  If you have no experience and you want to learn something new (for say MVC) then I say give the technology a try.  That is if you have the time / patience.  If it is a project that has a deadline and you do not know (say MVC) I say stick to what you are experienced with.

You may already have classes (dll  files) that handle the BLL and DAL and can be reused in say (webforms) and that is a time saver too!

Comment: "You may already have classes (dll files) that handle the BLL and DAL and can be reused in say (webforms) and that is a time saver too!"

You read my mind a little :)